# Vimeo update, mute/unmute not working. After Vimeo update on Feb 2023

Tags: vimeo

Looks like today (Feb 8, 2023) or a few days ago Vimeo did some updates. And now on all my websites, the following code is not working anymore (over 10 websites, all stopped working today).
Code for mute and unmute:

```
var iframe = $('.videobg iframe');
var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
$( ".videobg .unmute " ).click(function() {
    player.setVolume(1);
    $( ".videobg .unmute " ).hide();
    $( ".videobg .mute " ).show();
});
$( ".videobg .mute " ).click(function() {
    player.setVolume(0);
    $( ".videobg .unmute " ).show();
    $( ".videobg .mute " ).hide();
});
```

0 errors in console.log.

Can't find any Vimeo documentation updates.
I saw few other websites with similar functionality aren't working eather.

Anyone knows a new way to unmute a video?

Please note:
This is not a browser issue with "allow=autoplay". Thank you!

Comment: VIMEO fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

VIMEO fixed the issue.
No changes are required.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Change `player.setVolume(1)` to use `player.setMuted(false)` instead.